# Interpolate Through Multiple Surfaces with Sverchok

Tags: procedural, sverchok, interpolation

###### Short Summary

I am trying to interpolate through multiple surfaces, using the Sverchok addon. Essentially, I'm looking for a way to replicate the functionality of the Surface Lerp node, but for more than two surfaces.

###### More Details

Consider this node setup, which I started with:

[image]

[image]

In order to interpolate between these surfaces I then made this:

[image]

Which is great, I could then use the t value in the Vector Interpolation node to interpolate a surface at that t value. However, I want to take this a step further by passing a number range into the t value like so:

[image]

Which produces:

[image]

When the expected result should look like:

[image]

And so this is where I'm stuck, and my question is, **how can I pass a number range into the Vector Interpolation node, so that I can have multiple interpolated surfaces?**

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, was able to figure it out finally:

[image]

[image]